# My javascript search function in my local site keeps returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

So i have a problem with the search function, I just need to search for strings and show results on page, currently using Javascript and HTML, this is my code.

```
<form id="searchForm" action="javascript:findString();" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
    <div class="form-group waves-effect waves-light">
          <input type="text" id="searchItem" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          <input class="btn" type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('searchForm').submit(); return false;" value="Search" />
    </div>
</form>
```

And then this is my Javascript function I have

```
var TRange = null;
var str = document.getElementById("searchItem");

function findString(str) {
    if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion) < 4) return;
    var strFoun;
    if (window.find) {

        // CODE FOR BROWSERS THAT SUPPORT window.find

        strFound = self.find(str);
        if (!strFound) {
            strFound = self.find(str, 0, 1);
            while (self.find(str, 0, 1)) continue;
        }
    } else if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {

        // EXPLORER-SPECIFIC CODE

        if (TRange != null) {
            TRange.collapse(false);
            strFound = TRange.findText(str);
            if (strFound) TRange.select();
        }
        if (TRange == null || strFound == 0) {
            TRange = self.document.body.createTextRange();
            strFound = TRange.findText(str);
            if (strFound) TRange.select();
        }
    } else if (navigator.appName == "Opera") {
        alert("Opera browsers not supported, sorry...")
        return;
    }
    if (!strFound) alert("String '" + str + "' not found!")
    return;
}
```

Comment: Indent your code before submitting your question.

Comment: You are not returning anything from the function, hence it will return undefined. It is finding string on page correctly. What is the issue ?

Comment: all your returns are just that ... `return;` ... equivalent of `return undefined;` ...

Answer (score 0):

in your code str is the element, you need to get its value.

```
var TRange = null;

function findString() {
  var str = document.getElementById("searchItem").value;

  ...
```

Comment: I tried that at first to return the value, howeverit kept returning undefined, is there anything I should return directly in the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues with the script.

1. You are calling the function findString() onSubmit without passing the parameter, Hence you are getting undefined.
2. The code to get search text is placed outside of the function

`var str = document.getElementById("searchItem");`

Hence, it will be executed only on initial page load and str it will not return the current text from the input whenever you hit submit.

3. The str will have only the dom object and not the search string. So change it to

`var str = document.getElementById("searchItem").value;`

Finally, your script should look like this.

```
var TRange = null;

function findString() {
var str = document.getElementById("searchItem").value;

//rest of the search code goes here

}
```

Comment: Ok so I fixed all those errors, I just need to know one last thing, What parameter do I pass into the function findString();

Comment: I tried putting the id element of the input field but it didnt work.

Comment: <form id="searchForm" action="findString(searchItem);" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
    <div class="form-group waves-effect waves-light">
          <input type="text" id="searchItem" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          <input class="btn" type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('searchForm').submit(); return false;" value="Search" />
    </div>
</form>

Comment: You don't have to pass anything to the function findString(); I just updated my answer. since, we have moved the statement inside function. So the variable str will receive the current value whenever the function is called.

Comment: Here is the Plunker url where the script is working fine
https://embed.plnkr.co/G7HSe4jDPOwaZcTzJgrh/

Comment: I keep getting this:  Cannot GET /findString()?    ... any ideas

Comment: Must of been something in the JS i was messing up.